# React: trigger re-auth after some time

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I am working on this app, and when I log in I put my accessToken and some basic infos to the localStorage. the API i'm working on doesnt

Now what I want to happen is to prompt a modal 'fill in the password to continue' in a set amount of time lets say 1hr which is like a re-auth thing for the users.

I already have my modal, things I tried was putting a 'setTimeout' within the login function to fire the prompt in an amount of time - yeah works but if I try to refresh the page before the time then it won't.

Next was I tried putting the same function to a useEffect on my homepage - it also works but when I refresh the page, it won't work the way it should because it resets every refresh.

So what are my options here? halp! should I try putting in the localstorage or variable, the time the user logged in? and a time when it should expire? if so how will I trigger the function to run the check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add the next time the prompt should appear(say one hour from now) to the basic info in localStorage? Then use setInterval (instead of setTimeout) to periodically check the localStorage if that saved time has been reached?
Then display the modal(and delete the accessToken) if the current time is greater than that.

Comment: ohhh so setInterval runs regularly with the given amount of time, while setTimeout is only once.. ok shesh, then I should put it in a useEffect?

Comment: yes sir...  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

Comment: It should work without the useEffect. You could get rid of the useEffect (if it doesn't have  any parameters in the [ ])

Comment: so where should I include it? within the log in? homepage? it doesnt matter when changing pages? routes?

Comment: The easiest would be in a component that will be available in all the pages, (something like the footer).. but you should probably structure your website better to make it a separate component and add it somewhere up in the hierarchy

Comment: Thank you, i got what i wanted, I used momentjs also to easily compare the time